# Using Generics in Custom LinkedHashMap Cache Class

Tags: java

I'm trying to see if modifying a custom cache implementation to use generics in the `LinkedHashMap` instead of `LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>`.  I presume the `<Object, Object>` is suitable, but what is the best practice?  Does the use of generics make sense?

```
public class Cache extends LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4297992703249995219L;
    private final int cacheSize;
    public Cache(int size){
        super(size + 1, .75f, true); 
        this.cacheSize=size;
    }

     protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<Object, Object> eldest) {
        return size() > cacheSize;
     }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cache cache = new Cache(2);
        cache.put(1, "one");
        cache.put(2, "two");

        for(Entry<Object, Object> entry : cache.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should make the cast generic.

Comment: @SLaks - I can't get it to compile when I try that...

Comment: Where is there a cast in this code segment?

Comment: I've added an example java main example using the Cache Object with Generics, is this proper?  What do I gain with Entry<?, ?> vs Entry<Object, Object>?

Comment: Why do you need generics? Will `Cache` only store `Entry<Integer, String>`?

Comment: I wanted to make it open in that it could store any object

Comment: @c12: I meant _class_; sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your `Cache` class to be generic as well, declare it as such:

```
public class Cache<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V>{
```

Then you can declare, for instance,

```
Cache<Integer,String> cache = new Cache<>();
...
cache.put(1,"String 1");
cache.put(2,"String 2");
```

However, if what you want is a *heterogeneous* collection, where you can do

```
cache.put(1,"String 1");
cache.put(new MyObject1(), new SomeOtherObject());
```

Then this is stretching the capabilities of the Java generic system.  You will need to use `<Object,Object>` and save a class tag with each entry so you can know the runtime type when you need it.

Comment: how would that impact the for(Entry<Object, Object>...I tried Entry<K, V> but it wont compile. Any ideas?

Comment: `<K,V>` is meaningful only inside the `Cache` class.  In the `main` program you have to specify the actual classes.  In your case, it would be `Entry<Integer,String>`